# Verb to describe “unfootnoting”

Tags: single-word-requests

In describing the changes made to a scientific paper, I want to say that I removed a footnote and inserted its contents into the main text. More specifically I want to write something along the lines of:

> I defootnoted a footnote that addresses this issue.

As this sounds rather clumsy, **I am looking for a verb to replace *defootnote* here**.

Straightforward choices that do not fit include:

- *remove [the footnote]* – does not capture that the content of the footnote is preserved.
- *include [the footnote]* – can be misunderstood as a new footnote having been created.
- *include [the content]* – does not capture that the content existed before.

Also, searching the Internet for *defootnote* and *unfootnote* yields all sorts of unrelated stuff.

<sup>I eventually came up with a [satisfying solution](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/280444/42471) but would be interested whether there are other or better suggestions.</sup>

Comment: "I removed a footnote and inserted its contents into the main text." Beautiful English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Do you want to criticise or praise my writing style or do you want to suggest that I actually write this in my description of changes?

Comment: I'm wondering why you're toying with alternatives bordering (at least) on the unacceptable when there's a simple and elegant phrasing you are already aware of. As an academic request for a possible verb to work here, I could understand your question. But so often we get requests for help with things like 'I want to express _Victorian dovecote_ in a single word'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well, the problem with the expression is that it is not that beautiful anymore if I insert a lengthy relative clause describing the contents of the footnote. Also, it puts a lot of focus on something that is rather a sidenote in the text I am talking about. Consider: *To avoid the misunderstanding that our method can also be applied to transmogrify bananas, we removed a footnote that detailed the inevitable issues arising from the high carbohydrate content and incompatibilities of banana peels with the employed flux compensators and inserted its contents into the main text.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the term *[inlined](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inline)* (common in the programming domain), where a reference to an object is replaced by a copy of the object itself.

Comment: OP asks for a verb. I can't find a dictionary licensing _inline_ as such. I notice your reference is solely for the participial adjective (which can exist without a related verb). // It does appear that 'inline' is used as a verb on the internet; a Google search for "inlined a" is useful.

Comment: +1 I think this is a reasonable option (even though _inline footnote_ seems to a a set term for some typesetting systems, and means something else). Other options of that kidney include _pull in_ or _pull up_ the footnote.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come up with so far is ***to surface***:

> I surfaced a footnote that addresses this issue.

As an intransitve verb, its meanings include *to appear or become obvious after being hidden or not seen*[¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surface), which exactly describes the process and it is also used as a transitve verb in the sense of *to bring to the surface* [¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surface).

Comment: But the word is not used in this particular manner: it sounds outlandish when 'footnote' is used as the direct object.